# Editing cells in a datagrid winform with var type datasource

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, edit

I'm trying to edit a column of in the datagrid but it just simply refuses to edit. I've set editmode but it still wouldn't respond. My only conlcusion is the datasource that I'm binding it to. Here's some of my code:

```
public partial class Example: Form
{
    DataTable edtable = new DataTable();
    DbHelper db;

    public Example()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        db = new DbHelper("dbname", "dbid", "dbpassword");
        var cmd = db.GetCommand(
"Select ED.ID, ED.Name, ED.Code from EXAMPLETABLE ED Join (Select trim(code) as code, count(code) as codecount from exampletable group by trim(code)) X ON X.codecount > 1 and ED.Code like X.Code || '%'"
        ); 
        edtable = db.ExeGetDataTable(cmd);
        dataGridView1.DataSource = edtable;
    }               
}
```

When I run my app, my datagrid is populated with the `edtable` that contains contents obtained via the query. However, I cannot edit any of the values in them. I click on the cells and its as if the values are read only even though I specifically set editmode to be edit.

Is it because of my datasource? If so, how can I make my values editable?

Thanks!

Comment: Check properties of the dataGridView1 if:

`dataGridView1.EditMode = EditOnKeystrokeOrF2;
dataGridView1.Enabled = true;
dataGridView1.ReadOnly = false;`

each column has 
`ReadOnly = false`

Comment: I have done all that. I'm pretty sure it has something to do with my datasource but I'm not sure what :(

Comment: I agree with pistipanko.  By defalut, DataGridView in WinForms defaults to EditOnKeystrokeOrF2.  It may look read only but you could double click the cell, press F2 or simply start typing it should override the value.

Comment: That's what I thought too. It really did confuse me as well. After running the query, my datagrid gets populated with 3 columns and none of them are editable.

Comment: Check all event handlers of dataGridView1, at first the CellBeginEdit, EditingControlShowing and so on, there could be som code that prevents the control from editing.

Comment: Nope. I do not see anything out of the ordinary. In fact, I don't even have any event handlers.

Comment: It could be that my columns are set to read only by default. I could try making the columns read write but im literally creating the entire table on the datagrid during runtime. Is it even possible to do what I just said (i.e: forcing columns to become read write)? As you can tell, I'm a newbie :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you've about got it in your last comment. I know that when you bind to a data source, if you bind to a read-only property, the cells in the `DataGridView` will be read-only no matter what the `EditMode` or `ReadOnly` or any of its other properties are set to. I haven't bound to one of the `DataTable` objects you're using, but I know that when you bind to a class object with `{ get; }` properties, those are read-only in the grid, while `{ get; set; }` properties are editable.

Are you expecting that when you edit values in the grid, the values will be updated in the database? If so, I'm sure you need something more than an object populated from a simple `SELECT` statement. How you attack this will depend on what you expect to happen to the values edited in the grid.

Comment: Yup you're right. All I had to do was set the Readonly property of columns in **edtable** as false and the rest was simply poetry!

Comment: Yup. And for further clarification (for other newbies) The code I used is: edtable.Columns["Column name"].ReadOnly=False